# Facebook JavaScript SDK sometimes works other times not

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using on my website Facebook like using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fbBtnLike = '(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=124380934395811&version=v2.0";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));';

    var openFollow = function(){
            if(loadedSocial == 0) {
                eval(titterBtn + fbBtnLike + googlePlusBtn);
                loadedSocial=1;
            }
        };

    $('#openFollow').hover(function(){openFollow();});
});
```

The weird thing is I am not getting any errors.

Also it works some of the times other times it does not work. It's very random.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a jquery ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fbBtnLike = '(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=124380934395811&version=v2.0";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, \'script\', \'facebook-jssdk\'));';

    var openFollow = function(){
                if(loadedSocial == 0) {
                    eval(titterBtn + fbBtnLike + googlePlusBtn);
                    loadedSocial=1;
                }
            };

    $('#openFollow').hover(function(){openFollow();});
    });
```